# Trying to fix a Fsroot error using first aid in disk utility

Tags: hard-drive

I'm on iMac running Sonoma OS14.I keep getting some weird errors to do with the fsroot tree coming up on my hard drive when I run drive genius and first aid on disk utility in recovery mode. I found a code online that people said would clear the errors and I think it has.

Here's the code I found and ran: `diskutil unmountdisk /dev/disk3`, `fsck_apfs -oWT /dev/disk3~ My hard drive appeared to have a long bunch of nos and letters I hadn't noticed before after the volume name with UUID.....

At the end of the first aid process it said:

> The volume /dev/rdisk1s1 with UUID 1C76A740-CF8B-4143-9D6F-01725A431689 appears to be OK. File system check exit code is 0. Restoring the original state found as mounted.

My iMac seems to be running okay but I want to get rid of the `...with UUID 1C76A740-CF8B-4143-9D6F-01725A431689` if possible?

I should note when When I ran the code there were a couple of questions asked relating to the HD and I wasn't sure how to answer them in code so I just typed in "Y". Did I stuff anything up by typing in Y (for Yes - affirmative)? And what should I have typed in to answer a question "yes" in code please?

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: There's a lot of confusion here. You say you ran fsck on disk3 but your quoted report says disk1. All partitions & volumes have a UUID, that's how the Mac recognises them. I have no idea what you said 'yes' to, so I can't even comment on  that.See https://keith.github.io/xcode-man-pages/fsck_apfs.8.html